# Graphical GUI for Graphviz on Mac?

Tags: macos, charts, graphviz

I installed the Graphviz GUI from pixelglow.com, but it appears to only be a viewer for .dot Graphviz files. I am looking for a graphical *editor*, where I can create diagrams by pointing and clicking--just like the iPhone app Instaviz.

I would rather not code graphs by hand.

Does anyone know of anything--preferably free?

Comment: [Relevant question on softwarerecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/47442/1805). For a point and click editor the [magjac suggestion in my answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/82678/1805) should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean pixelglow.com which is a nice implementation of graphviz, I believe it includes dotty. If dot writing isn't actually a requirement you might check out the following:

[Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/) is by far the best app on the Mac for making graphs but it cannot export back to dot, and is not free (but does have a 20 object free limitation).

[Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) is also nice (webapp).

You can also try getting Dia from fink but YMMV

Comment: +1 Dia can export Dot.  Even though it is 'attributed' dot, it's an excellent suggestion.

Comment: Oops...yeah, I meant pixelglow.com Yeah, I want something simple, like the iPhone app. Omnigraffe is too much, and it's too expensive for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Graphviz comes with [dotty](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dottyguide.pdf). It's not included in the [Mac Version](http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/)?

Comment: I tried it, but all I can do is draw ellipses. Unless I am missing something, it is useless. I can't draw other shapes, and I can't connect shapes with lines.

Comment: You can. Check out the dotty guide: http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/dottyguide.pdf.  But based on your experience so far, I would go with a simpler tool that can export dot, such as Dia.

Comment: Get Dia from darwin ports: http://dia.darwinports.com/

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [graphviz-visual-editor](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/):

```
git clone https://github.com/magjac/graphviz-visual-editor
cd graphviz-visual-editor
npm install
make
npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Leonhard](https://github.com/glejeune/Leonhard) - but I've always found it difficult to find the app again. Hopefully putting the link here will help!

Answer (score 0):

[Graph Galaxy](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/graph-galaxy/id1473722262) is a modern WYSIWYG editor for Graphviz.

You can use it to create a large graph without writing any source code. It has an intuitive and efficient user interface. One of the most powerful features is that it implements a full-featured attribute system to support the cascading style. That means it's easy to set the default attributes for graph components.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is commercial software with a subscription-based business model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Awesome GraphViz](https://github.com/CodeFreezr/awesome-graphviz) page on GitHub. You might find something you like there.